# Overfitting on my model classification images CNN

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tf.keras

I tried a lot to make a change in my validation accuracy by adding layers and dropout but still, I have no change yet my accuracy is upper than 95% and my validation accuracy is always stuck in 88%.

my split :

```
x_train,x_validate,y_train,y_validate = train_test_split(x_train,y_train,test_size = 0.2,random_state = 42)
```

after splitting data (shape) :

```
x_train shape: (5850,)
x_train shape: (5850,)
x_validate shape: (1463,)
y_validate shape: (1463,)
x_test shape: (2441,)
y_test shape: (2441,)
```

width and height and number of channels :

```
width, height, channels = 64, 64, 3
```

after converting images to array (shape) :

```
Training set shape :  (5850, 64, 64, 3)
Validation set shape :  (1463, 64, 64, 3)
Test set shape :  (2441, 64, 64, 3)
```

and I have `6 classes`

augmentation :

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        featurewise_center=True,  
        samplewise_center=True,  
        featurewise_std_normalization=True,  
        samplewise_std_normalization=True, 
        zca_whitening=False,  
        rotation_range=0.9, 
        zoom_range = 0.7, 
        width_shift_range=0.8,  
        height_shift_range=0.8,  
        horizontal_flip=True,  
        vertical_flip=True) 
datagen.fit(x_train)
```

my Sequential :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16,(3,3),input_shape = (224,224,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())


model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3)))  
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())


model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3)))  
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())

model.add(Conv2D(128,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())


model.add(Conv2D(256,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(numberOfClass)) # output
model.add(Activation("softmax"))

model.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy",
              optimizer = "adam",
              metrics = ["accuracy"]) 
batch_size = 256
```

I put an early stopping in my code to make the best less validation loss, how can improve my validation accuracy to at least 92%?

```
Epoch 1/100
29/29 [==============================] - 62s 2s/step - loss: 0.4635 - accuracy: 0.3040 - val_loss: 0.4227 - val_accuracy: 0.4007

Epoch 00001: val_loss improved from inf to 0.42266, saving model to ./model_best_weights.h5
Epoch 2/100
29/29 [==============================] - 60s 2s/step - loss: 0.4230 - accuracy: 0.3260 - val_loss: 0.4046 - val_accuracy: 0.3314

Epoch 00002: val_loss improved from 0.42266 to 0.40463, saving model to ./model_best_weights.h5
Epoch 3/100
29/29 [==============================] - 60s 2s/step - loss: 0.3833 - accuracy: 0.4234 - val_loss: 0.3417 - val_accuracy: 0.5125

Epoch 00003: val_loss improved from 0.40463 to 0.34174, saving model to ./model_best_weights.h5
Epoch 4/100
29/29 [==============================] - 60s 2s/step - loss: 0.3351 - accuracy: 0.5040 - val_loss: 0.3108 - val_accuracy: 0.5432

Epoch 00004: val_loss improved from 0.34174 to 0.31083, saving model to ./model_best_weights.h5
Epoch 5/100
29/29 [==============================] - 59s 2s/step - loss: 0.3002 - accuracy: 0.5683 - val_loss: 0.2655 - val_accuracy: 0.6247

Epoch 00005: val_loss improved from 0.31083 to 0.26553, saving model to ./model_best_weights.h5
Epoch 6/100
29/29 [==============================] - 60s 2s/step - loss: 0.2794 - accuracy: 0.6025 - val_loss: 0.2677 - val_accuracy: 0.6194

Epoch 00006: val_loss did not improve from 0.26553
Epoch 7/100
29/29 [==============================] - 60s 2s/step - loss: 0.2606 - accuracy: 0.6374 - val_loss: 0.2524 - val_accuracy: 0.6477

Epoch 00007: val_loss improved from 0.26553 to 0.25239, saving model to ./model_best_weights.h5
Epoch 8/100
29/29 [==============================] - 59s 2s/step - loss: 0.2400 - accuracy: 0.6751 - val_loss: 0.2232 - val_accuracy: 0.6997

Epoch 00008: val_loss improved from 0.25239 to 0.22320, saving model to ./model_best_weights.h5
Epoch 9/100
29/29 [==============================] - 60s 2s/step - loss: 0.2307 - accuracy: 0.6875 - val_loss: 0.2092 - val_accuracy: 0.7181

Epoch 00009: val_loss improved from 0.22320 to 0.20916, saving model to ./model_best_weights.h5
Epoch 10/100
29/29 [==============================] - 59s 2s/step - loss: 0.2085 - accuracy: 0.7284 - val_loss: 0.2092 - val_accuracy: 0.7255

Epoch 00010: val_loss did not improve from 0.20916
Epoch 11/100
29/29 [==============================] - 60s 2s/step - loss: 0.1961 - accuracy: 0.7463 - val_loss: 0.1943 - val_accuracy: 0.7603

Epoch 00011: val_loss improved from 0.20916 to 0.19435, saving model to ./model_best_weights.h5
Epoch 12/100
29/29 [==============================] - 60s 2s/step - loss: 0.1894 - accuracy: 0.7621 - val_loss: 0.1829 - val_accuracy: 0.7669

Epoch 00012: val_loss improved from 0.19435 to 0.18294, saving model to ./model_best_weights.h5
Epoch 13/100
29/29 [==============================] - 60s 2s/step - loss: 0.1766 - accuracy: 0.7770 - val_loss: 0.1751 - val_accuracy: 0.7780

Epoch 00013: val_loss improved from 0.18294 to 0.17508, saving model to ./model_best_weights.h5
Epoch 14/100
29/29 [==============================] - 60s 2s/step - loss: 0.1606 - accuracy: 0.8006 - val_loss: 0.1666 - val_accuracy: 0.8005

Epoch 00014: val_loss improved from 0.17508 to 0.16662, saving model to ./model_best_weights.h5
Epoch 15/100
29/29 [==============================] - 60s 2s/step - loss: 0.1531 - accuracy: 0.8105 - val_loss: 0.1718 - val_accuracy: 0.7816

Epoch 00015: val_loss did not improve from 0.16662
Epoch 16/100
29/29 [==============================] - 61s 2s/step - loss: 0.1449 - accuracy: 0.8265 - val_loss: 0.1600 - val_accuracy: 0.8083

Epoch 00016: val_loss improved from 0.16662 to 0.16000, saving model to ./model_best_weights.h5
Epoch 17/100
29/29 [==============================] - 62s 2s/step - loss: 0.1309 - accuracy: 0.8419 - val_loss: 0.1609 - val_accuracy: 0.8202

Epoch 00017: val_loss did not improve from 0.16000
Epoch 18/100
29/29 [==============================] - 60s 2s/step - loss: 0.1165 - accuracy: 0.8607 - val_loss: 0.1572 - val_accuracy: 0.8222

Epoch 00018: val_loss improved from 0.16000 to 0.15722, saving model to ./model_best_weights.h5
Epoch 19/100
29/29 [==============================] - 60s 2s/step - loss: 0.1109 - accuracy: 0.8711 - val_loss: 0.1523 - val_accuracy: 0.8370

Epoch 00019: val_loss improved from 0.15722 to 0.15225, saving model to ./model_best_weights.h5
Epoch 20/100
29/29 [==============================] - 60s 2s/step - loss: 0.1008 - accuracy: 0.8877 - val_loss: 0.1405 - val_accuracy: 0.8484

Epoch 00020: val_loss improved from 0.15225 to 0.14046, saving model to ./model_best_weights.h5
Epoch 21/100
29/29 [==============================] - 60s 2s/step - loss: 0.1063 - accuracy: 0.8764 - val_loss: 0.1514 - val_accuracy: 0.8390

Epoch 00021: val_loss did not improve from 0.14046
Epoch 22/100
29/29 [==============================] - 61s 2s/step - loss: 0.0880 - accuracy: 0.8979 - val_loss: 0.1423 - val_accuracy: 0.8550

Epoch 00022: val_loss did not improve from 0.14046
Epoch 23/100
29/29 [==============================] - 60s 2s/step - loss: 0.0750 - accuracy: 0.9196 - val_loss: 0.1368 - val_accuracy: 0.8632

Epoch 00023: val_loss improved from 0.14046 to 0.13678, saving model to ./model_best_weights.h5
Epoch 24/100
29/29 [==============================] - 60s 2s/step - loss: 0.0712 - accuracy: 0.9218 - val_loss: 0.1520 - val_accuracy: 0.8521

Epoch 00024: val_loss did not improve from 0.13678
Epoch 25/100
29/29 [==============================] - 60s 2s/step - loss: 0.0664 - accuracy: 0.9288 - val_loss: 0.1600 - val_accuracy: 0.8451

Epoch 00025: val_loss did not improve from 0.13678
Epoch 26/100
29/29 [==============================] - 60s 2s/step - loss: 0.0605 - accuracy: 0.9360 - val_loss: 0.1528 - val_accuracy: 0.8636

Epoch 00026: val_loss did not improve from 0.13678
Epoch 00026: early stopping
```

images of my graph :

```
https://i.imgur.com/pNYwcE8.jpg
https://i.imgur.com/ZCSRI8e.jpg
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, I am afraid this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should experiment more, but glancing at your code, I can give you the following tips:

- according to the plot, validation accuracy is increasing a bit even in the end, maybe you can try to  increase `EarlyStopping` patience and monitor validation accuracy instead of validation loss
- add [batch normalization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/BatchNormalization) into your architecture
- increase dropout rate, maybe to some value between 0.4 and 0.7
- tune learning rate, and maybe use some learning rate scheduler like [ReduceLROnPlateau](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ReduceLROnPlateau) which might help to train even further after there is no increase in validation metrics

Good luck!

Comment: the best solution ever thanks!
I have another problem when I fixed val loss :
https://imgur.com/pXa9kjC 
now I have val accuracy fluctuating there's a solution?